# Function evaluation contained in an integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

How do i go about solving this form of equation

$$f(x)= \int_{0}^{x}(1-f(x-x'))e^{-zx'}dx'$$

I tried leibnitz to form a differential equation but couldn't proceed much further

Comment: Sorry, wrote the wrong equation, but a smart way of tackling the prior problem! @sangchul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $g(x) = e^{zx}f(x)$. Then using the substitution $t = x - x'$,

$$ g(x) = \int_{0}^{x} (e^{zt} - g(t)) \, dt $$

and hence $g'(x) = e^{zx} - g(x)$ with $g(0) = 0$. This is easy to solve with the solution

$$ g(x) = \frac{e^{zx} - e^{-x}}{z+1} $$

and hence

$$ f(x) = \frac{1 - e^{-(z+1)x}}{z+1}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Take Laplace transform of both sides, use convolution formula:
$$F(s) = \left( \frac{1}{s}-F(s) \right) \frac{1}{s+z}\; .$$
Solve for $F(s)$:
$$F(s) = \frac{1}{s(s+z+1)}\; .$$
Inverse Laplace:
$$f(x) = \frac{1-e^{-x(z + 1)}}{z + 1} \; .$$